# Coding a shell in Python

Tags: python

I am coding a data entry system in Python, in which the user should also be able to submit 'commands', exactly like the Python shell works, or for example SAS or R interfaces. I would like to know how to code a shell. For examnple, it should provide a prompt (which cannot be deleted by the user, e.g. the >>> prompt in Python) and receive input from the user. Furthermore, once an entry is submitted, the user cannot go back, like in the DOS prompt, where you cannot go up a line, so to speak.

Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 5):

The [cmd.Cmd](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html) class is something that would help you build a shell-like application. 
Likewise, [cmd2](http://packages.python.org/cmd2/) is a nice upgrade from the above module. With these you can build a shell application that has command history, help menus, and smart command parsing. Don't build a REPL from scratch because these modules will probably suffice for your needs.

Comment: @Josh Lee, yes it does have some nice enhancements. I'll edit my answer to include cmd2 as well.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much for putting me on the right track. Will try it out tonight!

Answer (score 0):

I coded a whole `sh` implementation in Python a while back, but sadly I don't have the source.

Your basic code would be this:

```
while True:
  command = raw_input('>>> ')
  print 'You entered "{command}".'.format(command = command)
```

But if you need something more complicated than a simple `bash`-like shell, there are a few projects that might suit your needs:

- **[IPython](http://ipython.org/)**: Pretty solid shell. It's used by Sage and a bunch of other big projects.
- **[Python's native `cmd` class](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html)**: self explanatory. Not very feature rich, but it's the Python shell.

Comment: You did? Did it also use vt100 control chars?

Comment: Go easy on me. I coded the features that I actually used, which was enough of an implementation for me.

Comment: I only ask because I'm usually coding on windoze boxes, where the shell is lousy. Since I can't find a decent replacement that is more of a "first class citizen" than interix or cygwin, I've decided to write a python one. With a little help from [termEmulator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/termemulator/) I can get away from the terrible terminal too.

Comment: @Spencer: Have you tried the console application recommended by IPython? http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/install/install.html and search for "console"  It's not perfect, but you might find it useful.

Comment: @JS. yep, and it's fantastic at what it does. Which doesn't fit what I want, namely, a bash clone with features stolen from fish and msfconsole. Ipython is a python interpreter with shell convenience features. I'm coming from a different direction, and while I could probably get ipython to do what I want, I think it would be a fun project to work on.

Comment: @Spencer: Ok, well bash clone it ain't, but I wasn't referring to IPython but to the Windows *Console* app they created/support/recommend.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/

Comment: @JS. Console2 is a terminal, not a shell. Also, it has bugs from the design constraints, and I've run into speed and stability issues.

Comment: Thanks for the response Blender, I will look into the two links you sent (as soon as I can leave the office). My objective is really to create my own 'custom made' shell/console application in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [readline](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html) library (gets you fancy features like completion and history as well). Sadly, it's UNIX only, like it's underlying C library.

Comment: Windows based here. Thanks anyway for the response!